# how to return default value if no query string in url window.location.search

Tags: string, parsing, url

The code below will get the `URL variables..`

For example: http://www.example.com/index.php?id=1&image=awesome.jpg

Calling `getQueryVariable(“id”)` – would return “1”
Calling `getQueryVariable(“image”)` – would return “awesome.jpg”

```
    function getQueryVariable(variable)
    {
       var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
       var vars = query.split("&");
       for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
               var pair = vars[i].split("=");
               if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
       }
       return(false);
    }
```

What if i want to return default value with the URL without `query parameters`? http://www.example.com/index.php

I still want to return “id” value = “predefined value"

Comment: have a look up that function. better implementation is there - then try to modify by return values (hint. use var expr = val || default_value) 
https://github.com/marxistcheguevara/econaider/blob/master/app/views/econaider/results.erb#L282 (mamma mia, iəve forgotten to share the url -)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
        {  
           default_values= {'id':-1,'image':'123.jpg'}
           var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
           var vars = query.split("&");
           for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                   var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                   if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
           }
           return(default_values[variable] || false);
        }
```

Comment: please accept/upvote so that others know this is correct

Comment: @dramaqueen Just be aware that this will return a default value only if that key is not found, not if the url does not contain any query parameters, as you asked (if I understood correctly). But maybe this will fit your needs too.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions:

**1)** set a default options object and return the desired value of that key if the url contains no parameters.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
   var defaultValues = {
      id: 'predefined valie',
      image: 'defaultimage.jpg'
   }
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   if (vars.length == 0) return defaultValues[variable] || false;
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}

getQueryVariable('id'); //will return query parameter id or 'predefined value' if the url contains no parameters
```

**2)** or set the desired default value when calling the function.

```
function getQueryVariable(variable, defaultValue)
{
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var vars = query.split("&");
   if (vars.length == 0) return defaultValue || false;
   for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
           var pair = vars[i].split("=");
           if(pair[0] == variable){return pair[1];}
   }
   return(false);
}

getQueryVariable('id', 'predefined value'); //will return query parameter id or 'predefined value' if the url contains no parameters
getQueryVariable('image', 'defaultimage.jpg'); //will return query parameter image or 'defaultimage.jpg' if the url contains no parameters
```